# "My phone number" Incorrect

Tags: 8.0, settings

The number that is displayed in the phone settings page is not my number. This is on a Nokia Lumia 620 running Windows Phone 8 (8.0.10211.204).

Where does the phone get this number from? Is there a way it can be changed? What are the implications of it being wrong?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you able to temporarily put another sim card into the phone and see what happens?

Comment: Yes, I can try this but I will have to wait until the weekend to get hold of another micro SIM.

Comment: Try it out and append to your question the results of doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My phone is exactly the same and there is nothing you can do….

It usually happens when you want to keep your existing number and put it on a new SIM. In my case I went from a standard SIM to a Micro SIM.

As far as I’m aware there are no implications. It’s just the original number which the Phone has found on the card- before your settings were transferred.

Answer (score -1):

Sign in to windowsphone.com with your authorized email account. Go to account settings and under your phone you need to update your new number.